# animate rig with 3d coordinates

Tags: animation, coordinates

I have frame-by-frame x,y,z coordinates for each joint of a human skeleton. How can I use these to animate a rig? The coordinates aren't perfect so the length of the bones may vary slightly throughout the animation.

Do I have to calculate the angle and length of each bone in each frame to animate it? Or is there a way to do it directly from the coordinates?